# Linux software-RAID and bootloader

Tags: mdadm, software-raid

How is it ensured that Linux software-RAID superblock(for example version 1.2) can be created at 4KiB from the beginning of the drive? According to manual of `mdadm` it is. I mean isn't there a hazard that this area on the disk is already occupied for example by the GRUB2 stage 1.5?

In addition, if software-RAID is created using partitions for example
like this:

```
mdadm --create --verbose --level=1 --metadata=1.2 --chunk=64 --raid-devices=2 /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
```

..then how should one ensure that for example MBR/GPT is mirrored or bootloader data is mirrored which both are located outside of partitions?

Answer (score 3):

Your array isn't built on the raw disks, but partitions of those disks so mdadm isn't touching anything outside of the partition.  The reference to the "first 4k" is probably referenced from the beginning of `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdc1` which are the "drives" underlying the RAID.

To mirror the bootloader, you can just run grub2-install on both raw disks (e.g. `sdb` and `sdc`).  This will allow you to boot from either disk. I personally use this to be able to boot from either of my `sde` and `sdf` disks to my /boot which is a mdadm device (as is my /).